# Use Python generator's .send() when generator is wrapped to act as a context manager

Tags: python, generator

Python's contextlib provides wrappers to turn generators into context managers:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def gen():
    yield

with gen() as cm:
    ...
```

And generators provide the ability to send values into generators that just yielded:

```py
def gen():
    x = yield
    print(x)

g = gen()
next(g)
g.send(1234) # prints 1234 and raises a StopIteration because we have only 1 yield
```

Is there any way to get both behaviors at the same time? I would like to send a value into my context manager so that it can be used while handling `__exit__`. So something like this:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def gen():
    x = yield
    # do something with x

with gen() as cm:
    # generator already yielded from __enter__, so we can send
    something.send(1234)
```

I'm not sure if this is a good/reasonable idea or not.
I feel like it does break some layer of abstraction since I would be assuming that the context manager was implemented as a wrapped generator.

If it is a viable idea, I'm not sure what `something` should be.

Comment: Why not have the context return a *separate* generator (that possibly sets results inside the context generator)? Writing the context manager as a class instead of a wrapped generator would make what you want to do much easier as well. Do you actively need the specific setup of an ``@contextmanager`` generator that is ``send``able inside the context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The generator underlying a `@contextmanager` is directly accessible via its `gen` attribute. Since the generator cannot access the context manager, the latter must be stored before the context:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def gen():
    print((yield))  # first yield to suspend and receive value...
    yield           # ... final yield to return at end of context

manager = gen()     # manager must be stored to keep it accessible
with manager as value:
    manager.gen.send(12)
```

It is important that the generator has exactly the right amount of `yield` points - `@contextmanager` ensures that the generator is exhausted after exiting the context.

`@contextmanager` will `.throw` raised exceptions in the context, and `.send` `None` when done, for which the underlying generator can listen:

```py
@contextmanager
def gen():
    # stop when we receive None on __exit__
    while (value := (yield)) is not None:
        print(value)
```

---

In many cases, it is probably easier to implement the context manager as a custom class, though. This avoids complications from using the same channel to send/recv values and pause/resume the context.

```py
class SendContext:
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass

    def send(self, value):
        print("We got", value, "!!!")


with SendContext() as sc:
    sc.send("Deathstar")
```

Comment: Awesome! Agreed that it would be easier to implement the CM as its own class for this intended use, I just wanted to know if the other way (using the `.gen` attribute like you pointed out) is also possible. The context is a library that accepts a user-supplied generator and internally uses it as a context manager. So asking the users to write a class instead of a generator would be a different level of effort/change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible, and there is probably a better way to implement what you want.

The way that [contextmanager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) is implemented is described in [PEP 344](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/#generator-decorator) about the `with` statement. The contextmanager calls the `next` method twice on the user's generator function, once in the `__enter__` method and once in the `__exit__` method, both without sending in any value.

The way you might implement what you want would be roughly (untested):

```
def create_context_manager(value_you_want_to_pass):
    @contextmanager
    def gen():
        do_something_with(value_you_want_to_pass)
        yield the_object_for_with_statement
        do_something_else_with(value_you_want_to_pass)
    return gen

with create_context_manager(1234) as cm:
    do_something_with(cm)
```